# Why won't it draw the Koch curve

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle 
import random

screen = turtle.Screen()

X = 400
Y = 400
screen.setup(X, Y)

def drawKoch(ttl, length, generation):
    if (generation == 0 ):
        ttl.fd(generation)
        return
    else:
        drawKoch(ttl, length - 1, generation / 3)
        ttl.lt(60)
        drawKoch(ttl, length - 1, generation / 3)
        ttl.lt(120)
        drawKoch(ttl, length - 1, generation / 3)
        ttl.lt(60)
        drawKoch(ttl, length - 1, generation / 3)


turtle.clearscreen()
screen.reset()
screen.screensize(X, Y)


ttl = turtle.Turtle()
ttl.speed(10)
ttl.penup()
ttl.setposition(-X/2 + 10, -Y/2 + 50)
ttl.pendown()

sides = 3
gens = 3
length = 300
angle = ((sides - 2) * 180) / sides

for i in range(sides):
    drawKoch(ttl, length, gens)
    ttl.left(180-angle)
```

I'm not sure why it won't draw the koch curve. I just begin learning this language not long ago. I need some assistant on this.........hope you guys who know this can help me

Comment: You need to give more information. What *is* it doing? What debugging have you tried?

Comment: Py-not-good indeed.

Comment: It suppose to draw a fractal shape, koch curve. I tired changing the length and generation but it still doesnt work

Comment: You need to give more detail than just repeating "it (still) doesn't work." See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This question shares a dozen lines of (mostly no-op) code with [this question asked yesterday by New-to-python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44402080/5771269) as well as those same lines in [this question asked 2 days ago by unown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44395855/5771269).  Are you creating a new SO account for every question you ask?

Answer (score 1):

A bunch of problems:

- you are recursing like `length - 1, generation / 3` when it should be `length / 3, generation - 1`
- because of this, where `generation` should go 3, 2, 1, 0 (halt) instead it is going 3, 1.0, 0.333, 0.111, 0.037, 0.01234, 0.00411, 0.00137, ...  It never "equals" 0, so your function just keeps recursing
- you are using `generation` instead of `length` in `ttl.fd()`
- `ttl.lt(120)` should be `ttl.rt(120)`